# question on DateTime addtime in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

is there a function that would do this

```
DateTime1.minute=50
```

if i add 10 minutes it would add 1 hour and set minute to 0 and likewise

Answer (score 9):

There's the [AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) function.

Answer (score 6):

As [Darin Dimitrov mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989124/question-on-datetime-addtime-in-c/3989142#3989142), there is an [AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) function.

However, be aware that you can't just do:

```
dateTime1.AddMinutes(50);
```

`AddMinutes` returns a *new DateTime*, so you'll need to do:

```
dateTime1 = dateTime1.AddMinutes(50);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `TimeSpan` via `.Add()`

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan tenMinutes = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
now = now.Add(tenMinutes);
```

You can also `AddDays(int days)`, `AddHours(int hours)`, `AddMinutes(int minutes)`,`AddSeconds(int seconds)`, etc.

All of these functions return DateTime objects so you'll have to set the value equal to the return value of the method.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
now = now.AddMinutes(10);
```

Comment: This won't work.  now.Add(...) returns a new DateTime, which you're currently throwing away.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use the AddMinutes method if you just want to add minutes...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or a shorter code example

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.AddMinutes(50);

// some other logic here

dt.AddMinutes(10);
```

That should initially set it to 50mins and then adding another 10mins would make it an hour. You may want to consider using a TimeSpan instead though.

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
span += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

Console.WriteLine(span.Hours); // prints "1"
```